# Generate a go template with go template

Tags: go, go-templates

I want to generate something like `{{ .Values.something }}` using go templates.

But I can't figure out what my template should look like, for example, I thought of a template like this

```
`"{{.Values."{{ .Value }}"}}"`
```

And execute it against this struct

```golang
type values struct {
    Value string
}
```

But it didn't work, I tried some other combinations as well but no luck. Can someone help me figure out how can I get `{{ .Values.something }}` this output out of a go template.

Answer (score 2):

### I. Without changing the delimeters

You can't embed an `{{ }}` action in another `{{ }}` action, and that is what you tried. Since the `{{` and `}}` literals in templates are special (they are the *default* delimeters), you have to use an action to output those as literals, e.g.

```
{{ "{{" }}
```

And

```
{{ "}}" }}
```

So a viable solution:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`{{"{{"}} .Values.{{.Value}} {{"}}"}}`))

buf := &bytes.Buffer{}

params := map[string]interface{}{
    "Value": "Something",
}

if err := t.Execute(buf, params); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(buf.String())
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/j5_FycRYF7Y)):

```
{{ .Values.Something }}
```

Of course you can output `{{` and `.Values` with one action too, with this template:

```
{{"{{.Values."}}{{.Value}}{{"}}"}}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/alY6S7I9A6u).

You may also use the `print` builtin template function to do all that in one step:

```
{{ print "{{.Values." .Value "}}" }}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PXGz7suMQMM).

### II. With changing the default delimeters

All the above template kung-fu was required because we used a template to generate a template that both used the same delimeters.

If we change the delimeters of the generator template, our task becomes much simpler. Delimeters can be changed using the [`Template.Delims()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Delims) method.

So for examle if we change the left and right delimeters from (`{{`, `}}`) to (`<<`, `>>`), then the sequences `{{` and `}}` aren't special anymore, it can be used in templates and they will be outputted as-is.

So the following simple template will also do what you want:

```
{{ .Values.<<.Value>> }}
```

Example using it with changing the default delimeters:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").
    Delims("<<", ">>").
    Parse(`{{ .Values.<<.Value>> }}`))
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5uEpTXs4wFs).